# Python pandas - If 2 column equals to each other, add another column and say YES and NO, add another row if value not present

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 excel sheets A and B, below are the conditions (comparing col1 of both sheets):

-Sequence of rows should follow sheet A as end result

-If same item exists both col1 of Sheet B and col1 of sheet A, enter 'YES' in col3 on the same row in Sheet A

-If item does not exist in col1 of Sheet B and exists in sheet A, enter 'NO' in col3 on the row in Sheet A

-If item exists in col1 of Sheet B and does not exist in col1 of sheet A, append this in the next available row in col1 of sheet A

Example below

A:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
Dog Apple (empty)
Cat Banana (empty)
Bear Hotdogs (empty)
Wolf Lollipop (empty)
```

B:

```
Col1 Col2
Dog ax
Bear ad
Cat aw
Hamburger az
```

Expected result:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
Dog Apple Yes
Cat Banana Yes
Bear Hotdogs Yes
Wolf Lollipop No
Hamburger
```

Tried using np.where and .isin but keep getting errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

df  is your DataFrame A,
df2 is your DataFrame B

first, merge df and df2 and capture it in df3

create an array of df that include df3 and another one that is a result of merge df2 with df and rows that don't exists in df

finally using the reduce we merge the two dataframes

```
df3= df.merge(df2,  on='Col1' ,how='left' , suffixes=("","_y")) 
df3['Col3'] = np.where(df3['Col2_y'].isnull(), 'No','Yes' )

dfs = [df3,
       df2.merge(df, on='Col1', how='left', suffixes=("","_y")).query('Col2_y.isnull()').drop(columns='Col2_y')]



from functools import reduce
df3=reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Col1'],
                                            how='outer', suffixes=("","_y")), dfs).drop(columns=['Col2_y','Col3_y'])
df3
```

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3
0   Dog     Apple   Yes
1   Cat     Banana  Yes
2   Bear    Hotdogs     Yes
3   Wolf    Lollipop    No
4   Hamburger   NaN     NaN
```